# when does the svg onload function happen

Tags: javascript, svg

Given this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100px" height="100px" version="1.1"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
<text 
 x="20" 
 y="20" 
 onload="alert('load'); setAttribute('fill', 'fuchsia')"
 onclick="setAttribute('fill', 'lightgreen')"
 onmouseout="setAttribute('fill', 'black')"
>Load me</text>
</svg>
```

I would expect to see pink text when the svg was opened. onclick and onmouseout work as expected.

This doesn't happen in firefox. IE can't open it, period.

Any explanations?

Comment: For performance reasons Firefox only sends onload events to `<svg>` elements.

Answer (score 4):

Use `onload` event on `<svg>` element. This works fine on all browsers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<svg onload="init(evt)" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gui="http://www.kevlindev.com/gui">
    <script>var info,infoElem;

    function init(e) {
        if ( window.svgDocument == null )
            svgDocument = e.target.ownerDocument;

        infoElem = svgDocument.getElementById("info");
        infoElem.setAttributeNS(null,"fill", "fuchsia");
    }

    function changeColor(c){
        infoElem.setAttributeNS(null,"fill", c);
    }</script>
    <text id="info" x="20"  y="20" onclick="changeColor('lightgreen')" onmouseout="changeColor('black')">Load me</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
//snip...

    <svg width="100px" height="100px" version="1.1" onload="alert('load'); setAttribute('fill', 'fuchsia')"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >

//snip...
```

Comment: works for me too. Strange that <text onload.. doesn't seem to have any effect though...

Comment: that `<text onload...` doesn't work isn't stranger than the same not working in html, e.g `<div onload...`. Unless there's something external to load the element is fully loaded when you reach it, so you can put a script tag right after that element and expect to be able to get any element before the script tag in the document.

Comment: Sorry, don't get it. My thinking is that onload for element E is triggered when E is loaded. Is this not the case?