# When is onload invoked?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg, dom-events

This is supplementary to [when does the svg onload function happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917408/when-does-the-svg-onload-function-happen)

Suppose we have a document (html, svg or what have you) and the onload attribute is supported for some element, like this:

```
<doc>
<element onload="do(something)">
   content goes here
</element>
</doc>
```

I would expect do(something) to be invoked when the doc was opened. It seems that this isn't (always) the case.

Can anyone shed any light?